# Is there means for synchronizing data of my application and MS Outlook?

Tags: java, android

I have been developing Android applicatiom which should get dates from MS Outlook calendar. I can't find information/tutorials about how I can do it using USB connection. Please, tell me, is there any means for my task? Is there any tutorials how can I do it programmatically?

Comment: Where is stored the data that you want to synchronize ?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this [Android Forums post](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/337012-we-can-now-synchronize-outlook-android-without-3rd-party-app-exchange-server.html):

> Hallelujah! For Android version 2.2 or newer, we no longer need 3rd
>   party software or an Exchange Server to synchronize contacts and/or
>   calendar items with Microsoft Outlook or Windows Live Mail programs
>   (which I'll collectively refer to here as "Outlook").
>
> Hotmail, MSN Mail, & Microsoft Live Mail (which collectively I'll
>   refer to as "Hotmail") now enable synchronization between Outlook and
>   Android's standard, built-in apps for contacts (a.k.a. "people"),
>   calendar, and email through Android's built-in ActiveSync
>   functionality.... ([*read more*](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/337012-we-can-now-synchronize-outlook-android-without-3rd-party-app-exchange-server.html))

Comment: Yes I have. But it doesn't show me how I can get dates from MS Outlook calendar programatically. I need some libraries or something similar.

Comment: Then look [here](http://theregoesdave.com/2008/10/30/simple-outlook-to-android-g1-sync-solution/) ..

Comment: [Don't answer with just a link.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)